# Is it possible that someone deleted my comment but this is not listed in my activity?

Tags: support

I cannot find some comment that I wrote yesterday.

Not sure though, if my client app (Stack Exchange for iPad) actually has posted it.

Is it possible that a comment, or reply, or post is deleted (once posted successfully) without any trace at all?

Comment: Yes.  Deleted comments do not show up.  They are gone to all but mods and employees.

Comment: Your only deleted comment is here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859145/detect-ubuntu-on-windows-vs-native-ubuntu-from-bash-script/38859331#38859331. Posted on 10th Sept, deleted on 13 by a mod. No comment was deleted yesterday

Comment: It could be that the itself post is deleted. As noted in the (possible) duplicate, comments on deleted posts are also excluded from the activity view.

Comment: @Stijn but to note they are viewable if you can see and go to the deleted post. Comments that are *actually deleted* won't be.

Comment: Concerning your edit, do you mean the answer posted, or the banner about a possible duplicate? (As a side note, only you see that banner.) If the latter, you should explain in your question _how_ they missed the point, not just say that they did. If one person thinks it was the correct duplicate, others may as well if you don't clarify.

Comment: Kendra: it is a banner, the other reply was suggested by @Stijn. I've read it. Thank to you all who responded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a comment is deleted, it does not leave a trace for normal users. At least, in most cases.

It will remain visible to diamond moderators and employees, both on the main page and, if I recall correctly, when they examine your profile. This allows them to continue to moderate and see if the user has a history of nasty or hateful comments, even if they have been deleted. It also allows them to see the full context of a discussion or disagreement in comments on a post, even if one user has deleted some of their comments.

In some cases, and I am not fully sure of the specifics, a comment you post may stay in the inbox of another user. I believe, from personal experience, that this happens if you read the notification. The comment will not, however, appear in the user's "responses" tab when they look at their profile.

But you will not see the comment. A user cannot see their own deleted comments. It could have been deleted, if it was posted, for many reasons, including being flagged as "not constructive", "too chatty", or "obsolete." A comment being deleted is not necessarily a bad thing, so I wouldn't worry too much about that.